# Invalid column name in SQL query

Tags: sql-server

I'm a bit rusty in writing SQL Queries, I'm trying to output a list of 'Contacts' with no 'PAs'

```
select a.first_name, a.last_name, (select count(b.contact_id)) as "PA Count" 
from CRM_Contact a left join CRM_PA b on a.id = b.contact_id 
where [PA Count] = 0 
group by a.first_name, a.last_name
```

Could someone explain why I am getting the error message:

> Invalid column name 'PA Count'.

Comment: You can't refer to aggregates in `WHERE`, you need to use `HAVING`

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: What should I do instead, @Lamu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WHERE` can only use columns or their aliases. `PA Count` though is an *aggregate* that gets calculated *after* `WHERE`.

Filtering aggregates is performed with the `HAVING` clause :

```
SELECT a.first_name, 
       a.last_name, 
       COUNT(b.contact_id) as [PA Count]
FROM CRM_Contact a 
       LEFT JOIN CRM_PA b ON a.id = b.contact_id 
GROUP BY a.first_name, 
          a.last_name 
HAVING Count(b.contact_id) =0
```

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to `COUNT` then just use column name without `SELECT` statement and use `HAVING` statement after `GROUP BY`:

```
select 
  a.first_name
, a.last_name
, Count(b.contact_id) as "PA Count" 
from CRM_Contact a 
left join CRM_PA b on a.id = b.contact_id 
group by a.first_name, a.last_name
HAVING Count(b.contact_id) = 0
```

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to use `From` in the following query:

```
(select count(b.contact_id) from YourTable)
```

Comment: `SELECT` without a `FROM` is valid syntax; although it is odd in the context used. This, for example, will return the "expected" results. `SELECT I, (SELECT N) N
FROM (VALUES(1,2),(3,4))V(I,N);`